# I can't update the system I get the following error

Tags: system-installation

```
Reading package list ... Done
Creating dependency tree
Reading the status information ... Done
Calculating update ... Done
The packages listed below were installed automatically and are no longer required.
  libfprint-2-tod1 mousetweaks
Use "sudo apt autoremove" to remove them.
The following packages will be updated:
  bolt gnome-control-center-faces gnome-shell-extension-system76-power
  kernelstub libbrotli1 libbrotli1: i386 libfprint-2-2 libfprint-2-tod1 mdadm
  pop-default-settings pop-shell python3-urllib3 system76-power thermald
14 updated, 0 new will be installed, 0 to remove, and 0 not updated.
4 not fully installed or removed.
0B / 3,476 kB of files need to be downloaded.
27.6 kB will be released after this operation.
do you wish to continue? [Y / n] yes
Preconfiguring Packages ...
dpkg: Dependency issues preventing libglib2.0-0: i386 triggers from processing:
 libglib2.0-0: i386 depends on zlib1g (> = 1: 1.2.2); However:
 The `zlib1g: i386 'package is not configured yet.

# Repeated messages removed

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0: i386 (--configure):
 dependency issues - triggers will not be processed
No "apport" report was written because the value of "MaxReports" has already been reached
         dpkg: Dependency issues preventing libglib2.0-0: i386 triggers from processing:
 libglib2.0-0: i386 depends on zlib1g (> = 1: 1.2.2); However:
 The `zlib1g: i386 'package is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0: i386 (--configure):
 dependency issues - triggers will not be processed
No "apport" report was written because the value of "MaxReports" has already been reached
         dpkg: Dependency issues preventing libglib2.0-0: i386 triggers from processing:
 libglib2.0-0: i386 depends on zlib1g (> = 1: 1.2.2); However:
 The `zlib1g: i386 'package is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-0: i386 (--configure):
 dependency issues - triggers will not be processed
No "apport" report was written because the value of "MaxReports" has already been reached
         dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libglib2.0-0: i386
 ...
Process stopped due to too many errors.
E: Sub-process / usr / bin / dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

> NOTE: This post was run through Google Translate and repeated sections of identical error messages and repeated package entries (for the exact same package) were removed to reduce the size of the post and to properly translate.  The title was also translated; the original content can be found in the revision history.

Comment: The package broken here is `zlib1g` - have you tried actually installing it?  `sudo apt install -f` or `sudo apt install --reinstall zlib1g` may get through the process of reconfiguring it AND will provide error output specific to `zlib1g`'s failing to install.  Also, Ask Ubuntu is an English-only site, so running your posts through a translator will be required before posting on this site.

Comment: sorry it's my firs question in this forum I didn't know it is an english only site, about the problem yes I'd try sudo apt install -f and sudo apt install --reinstall zlib1g but they didn't work I get the following error "E: Internal Error, No file name for zlib1g:i386" thanks for take the time for answer me

Answer (score 2):

Had this same exact issue a few minutes ago the issue is `libglib2.0-0` re-install it and you should be fine.

`sudo apt install --reinstall libglib2.0-0`

Comment: Hi thanks for answering me I could solve it using this command "sudo dpkg --configure -a"